# electronic signature and digital certificate server on linux

Tags: digital-signature, digital-certificate, electronic-signature

Looking for solution to be able to allow our CRM users to sign online documents on our site , is there opensource solution for this ?

basically we will be signing the documents on behalf of the customer for the supplier but of course customer himself will be signing online, so here we will use one certificate to sign for different customers... timestamp and other features required to be the legal,

and if there is open source solution or one of small cost product would cover Annex1 and Annex2 all the required points
http://www.berr.gov.uk/files/file49952.pdf

we found this but would this work on Linux servers http://www.signfiles.com/digital-certificates/ and ItextPDF but would any of this be ok for legal side of things ?

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out a service like DocuSign which already has integrations with major CRMs.  Your main issue here is proving that it actually happened and that it's legally binding.  The best way to do this is not to have an open source solution that you control, but to rely on a trusted 3rd party.

Full disclosure: I work for DocuSign.